# Cannot use the official phobia definition

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be the best way to replace “afraid of dead people” with a single word in this sentence:

> A girl afraid of the dead protects nonviolent monsters ripped off their humanity from the atrocious humans, which are prepared to do anything not to become monsters they once were.

This is a logline for a script so it must be so simple that a child understands it without looking up in books or similar. I will probably cut out “ripped off their humanity” in the end version.

Comment: Could you include the words you found in your question?

Comment: Can you not find a way to explain the meaning of the 'official' names in your text? I would never guess 'fear of the dead' or 'of pain' from 'monstrophobic'. Not all fears are phobias. It would be helpful if you loosed at the Single-word-request tag info and formulated your question as it suggests, including an example sentence and your research.

Comment: People who know what -phobic means would think Monstrophobic was a fear of monsters.

Comment: What's wrong with "fear of the dead"?

Comment: I'm not sure your average reader would have any worse time understanding the 'official phobia' word you may have found over your suggested use of the word  'monstrophobic'. I would either settle for plain and clear English, or go with a technical word. To try and find some word that meets halfway is going to give you the best of neither world.

Comment: You say you don't want to use an unfamiliar word because readers wouldn't understand it, fair enough. Then you say you wanted to use [*monstrophobic*](http://phobia.wikia.com/wiki/Teraphobia) but you couldn't find it in Google Books. Well, it doesn't mean fear of death or  pain, but of monsters. But you were happy to cite such a  word if you had found support. So why not include a proper phobia such as [**Thanatophobia**](http://www.wikihow.com/Overcome-the-Fear-of-Death), it's documented, and readers will either know it, or look it up with the not small advantage of finding its definition.

Comment: @Syk Are you talking about a fear of dead bodies (inert corpses), or a fear of dead bodies who are walking about (zombies)? Or a fear of death itself? I'm not sure how you can have a word for fear of the dead **and** pain -- they are two entirely different concepts. The number of comments here, and the disparity of answers so far, indicates that the question is currently not clear enough.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A It is from a logline, and it has to be so simple that a child understands it, without looking up in books.
I meant fear of the dead people aka monsters, and – or pain. Two different things, since I did not decide which one will be more appropriate for the story.
The unfinished logline would be 
"A girl (afraid of the dead) protects nonviolent monsters ripped off their humanity from the atrocious humans, which are prepared to do anything not to become monsters they once were."

Comment: @Andrew Lach  I meant fear of the dead people aka monsters, and – or pain. Two different things, since I did not decide which one will be more appropriate for the story.

Comment: @oerkelens It is from a logline, and it has to be so simple that a child understands it.
I meant fear of the dead people aka monsters, and – or pain. Two different things, since I did not decide which one will be more appropriate for the story.
The unfinished logline would be 
"A girl (afraid of the dead) protects nonviolent monsters ripped off their humanity from the atrocious humans, which are prepared to do anything not to become monsters they once were."

Comment: Your clarification now makes the question *on-topic*, but you need to [**edit**](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/379903/edit) the question. Just include the very relevant context, copy and paste your comment about the TV synopsis, and I will immediately vote to reopen your question. A question needs five reopen votes before it can be opened again.

Comment: @Syk Add **all** information into the question, not comments. Also, questions should only ask one thing (or how else do you choose the best answer?). **Decide whether you want to ask about the dead, or pain,** and ask about that. If the former, then you do need to make clear exactly what sort of dead person you are asking about.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A 
I did as you suggested it. I hope it is okay now.

Comment: Your paragraph about the girl would benefit from some editing. At present I don't find it all all clear. You've said monster are dead people, yes? but 'a girl (afraid of the dead) protects nonviolent *dead people* ripped off their humanity from the atrocious humans, which are prepared to do anything not to become *dead people* they once were' is confusing in the extreme.

Comment: @Spagirl Which part exactly should be edited, or removed?
A shorter version would be: 
A monstrophobic girl protects nonviolent monsters from the atrocious humans, which are prepared to do anything not to become monsters they once were.
Or maybe
A monstrophobic girl protects nonviolent monsters from the atrocious humans, which took their bodies and are prepared to do anything not to become monsters they once were.
Since I cannot use monstrophoic or the official phobias “necrophobic,” I am searching for a short 1-2 word replacement of afraid of dead people.

Comment: @Spagirl Are these easy to understand aka logical:  
Forced into hiding for a crime he didn’t do, a despondent cop attempts to prove his innocence for a murder he has not yet committe.  
A cop who’s a mole and a mole who’s a cop battle to decide the fate of a legendary Boston mobster.  
A wrongfully convicted ex-con allows his crew to rob a jeweler while he creates a diversion by threatening to jump off the ledge of a hotel.  
A gunman struggles to protect an infant against a nefarious plot that involves harvesting babies for their bone marrow. - This line-break thing isn't working for me.

Comment: @Spagirl Or was the problem that there was not enough of the information in the sentence?
"A deviceful daughter afraid of dead people protects her family of non-violent monsters from her mother’s invention, atrocious humans, which are prepared to do anything not to become monsters they once were."

Comment: @Syk Sorry for the delay in answering. Problems included: I don't know what 'ripped off their humanity' means. Who ripped humanity off who? How do you even rip humanity off something? Did you mean 'stripped *of*'? 'Ripped off' means something different. I don't know what you mean by 'which are prepared to do anything not become monsters they once were' Who used to be monsters? If monsters are dead people how can that be something someone **used** to be. It needs editing because you are not communicating the story elements understandably.

Comment: @Spagirl
Thanks for the “stripped off” warning. I have removed that from the previous version.
The part - Who used to be monsters – it is the “atrocious humans, which are prepared to do anything not to become monsters they once were."
Allow me to explain it bit by bit – "The daughter" is a human, afraid of dead people aka monsters. "Her family" got turned into monsters by an event. She protects her family against "atrocious human" - once monsters - now turned (through that same event) into humans ready to do anything necessary not to become monsters again... The rest in part 2.

Comment: @Spagirl My recent logline is “A deviceful daughter afraid of dead people, protects her family of non-violent monsters from her mother’s experiment gone wrong, atrocious humans, prepared to do anything not to revert into monsters again.”
It is a flip-flop thing- The experiment turned humans into monsters and vice versa. Is there a shorter, easier to understand word combination I could use in this sentence?

Comment: @Syk I think your use of 'monster' to specifically mean 'dead-but-presumably-still-walking-and-talking-humans' is extremely confusing. Is your MC an 'atrocious human' or just a 'human', are 'atrocious humans' a thing in themselves or just humans who aren't very nice?  You might be better to start your logline with the situation *then* introduce the character. eg 'In a world where humans can turn to monsters and monsters to humans, a resourceful girl strives to protect her family from the results of an experiment gone wrong.'

Comment: @spagirl
I forgot the downside of the flip-flop. The experiment turned humans into monsters (by their looks), but they kept their human traits, aka humanity. The same experiment turned monsters into humans, which kept their monster traits, aggression, hunger to kill – a sort of a double flip flop. The main character remained through some wonder a human and must now protect her family of non-violent monsters against humans that were once monsters and now threaten them since they know the daughter works on her mother’s project to reverse the effect of the experiment.

Comment: @spagirl If I try this – "A resourceful girl afraid of monsters searches for a way to reverse her mother’s experiment that turned hideous monsters into humans on a hunt for fresh food, and her family into non-violent monsters."
Or if I try it your way - "In a world where humans turned into monsters and monsters into humans, a resourceful girl afraid of the undead strives to protect her family of non-violent monsters."

Comment: @Syk I don't think I'm being helpful to you. To my reading ALL of your options are utterly confusing and don't express the basics of  **what**, **who**, **why**or **how**. Focus on what people need to understand the gist. If its a flip-flop, find a way to say that..'In a horrifying reversal, humans look monstrous and monsters look human', but then you need to explain why that's a problem.if ALL monsters look human and vice versa then everyone know's who is who and just has to get used to them looking different.

Comment: @Syk if only SOME got changed, then you have a problem because you don't know who is human inside.What do monsters have to lose by being changed back, are they passing as human, are they safer, richer, more powerful as human? if it is the case that only some monsters and humans got changed, that needs to be clear so perhaps something like...'After an experiment goes wrong, no-one can tell who is monster and who is human, in this fatal masquerade where monsters lurk behind human faces a resourceful girl strives to save her family.'

Comment: @Syk So consider if it makes a difference in the logline whether you pack in the information about exactly who changed, or is it enough to know that there is change, danger, a family at risk and a heroine.  Anyway, I'm out of this thread now, good luck.  PS- I never did work out what the fear of the dead business was about and I suspect it it too complex to try and wedge it into the logline. There are monsters, why wouldn't she be afraid. Let people work that much out for themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use "necrophobic" to mean "scared of the dead". It isn't unimaginable for the average reader to understand "necro" as "dead".

Comment: It's more likely (I think) that *necrophobic* would be taken to mean "fear of death" rather than fear of those who have died. The *necro-* prefix indicates "death" or "corpse". I suppose it all depends on context, and we haven't been given any.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a hyphenated word, *pain-averse* is a good one for your second question (*pain-aversion* for a noun form).